# How can I scroll a lightbox outside the box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I have on my website some lightboxes and now I can scroll them only when my pointer is inside the box.

How can I scroll them outside the box, like when you open a comment on Trello or on Pinterest?

Here is my code:

```js
        //Declare vars
var $lightboxAnchor = $("a.list_message");

//Lightbox
$(".overlay-background").hide();

//Lightbox functions from leistungen
$lightboxAnchor.click(function() {
  var $attr = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
  console.log($attr);
  $('div[id=' + $attr + ']').show();
  $("body").addClass("noscroll");
});
$(".overlay-background").click(function() {
  console.log('alert');
  $(this).hide();
  $("body").removeClass("noscroll");
});

$(".close_lightbox").click(function() {
  console.log('alert');
  $(".overlay-background").hide();
  $("body").removeClass("noscroll");
});
```

```css
        .overlay-background {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height:100%;
        width: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 1000; /* high z-index */
        background: #000; /* fallback */
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    }

    .overlay-content 
    {
        display: block;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 1%;
        width: 70%;
        height:70%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 15%;
        left: 10%;
        margin: 0;
        cursor: default;
        z-index: 10001;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    }
```

```html
   <div class="overlay-background">
<div class="overlay-content">
   <object type="text/html" data="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dentist" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" </object>
</div>

</div>
```

I`ve made this JSFiddle as a representation: jsfiddle.net/9mesun50 As you can see the lightbox can be scrolled only inside it. If I have the pointer outside the lightbox I can scroll it.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Can you put together an example on JSFiddle?  It's not clear what you're asking without a visual representation.

Comment: Please use "Code Snippet" or any other online "code playgrounds" for better review.

Comment: I`ve made this JSFiddle as a representation: https://jsfiddle.net/9mesun50/ As you can see the lightbox can be scrolled only inside it. If I have the pointer outside the lightbox I can scroll it. Thanks